# SQL Server 2012 Evaluation(Expired)からStandardへアップグレード

Tags: sql-server

現在, SQL Server 2012 Evaluationを使用しており､評価期間が過ぎてしまったため､Standardにアップグレードをしようと考えております｡　既にStandardのメディアは手元にあり､検証環境にEvaluationをインストールし､Standardへのアップグレード方法は確認しています｡←これは評価期限が切れる前の状態

質問としては､評価期限が過ぎてしまったEvaluationエディションからStandardへ更新する事は可能でしょうか｡
MSのサイトを探していたのですが､答えとなるドキュメントに行き着けなかったため､こちらでご質問させていただきました｡

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoftの[サポート情報](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/971268)によりますと、期限の切れたSQL Server評価版は以下の手順で製品版へのアップグレードを行います。

- SQL Server 2008 R2以降

インストールセンターよりエディションの変更が可能です。

- SQL Server 2008

Setup.exeをコマンドラインより起動することでエディションの変更が可能です。

- SQL Server 2005

`SAVESYSDB`、`USESYSDB`オプションを使用した再インストールが必要です。

またアップグレード先ですが、[評価版からはスタンドアロン版の製品版全バージョンにアップグレードが可能](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143393.aspx)です。

Comment: pgrhoさん、ご回答ありがとうございます。大変助かりました。